# Haskell: problems with function prototype to find the position of an element within a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, position

who can help.

I am not a Haskell programmer, I just know a little bit of the language, very little. I have already looked at several posts here at *Stack overflow* and also elsewhere and I am not managing to fix what happens, despite understanding what actually happens.

I am developing basic instructional material on functional programming. In this material I also use another language (very simplistic), in addition to Haskell. In a code I'm having problems with data types in Haskell. The examples I am using must be kept at the same level of configuration and operational difficulty as shown below.

First of all, the code has to be as simple as possible without using language functions or libraries, without using *otherwise* or *where*, since the languages used in the material are only illustrative of the functional programming theory presented.

Here are the functions that work, but are used directly and indirectly in the function that is having a problem.

```
my_reverse :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
my_reverse [] = []
my_reverse (x : xs) = my_reverse xs ++ [x]

my_size :: (Num a) => [a] -> Int
my_size [] = 0
my_size (x : xs) = 1 + my_size xs

my_getpos :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> Int
my_getpos _ [] = error "element does not exist in the list"
my_getpos n (x : xs) = if n == x then my_size xs else my_getpos n xs
```

What I want is to get the element's position in the list. When I execute at the Haskell prompt the statement:

```
my_getpos 4 (my_reverse [1,2,3,4,5])
```

I get result ***3***, which is really expected. The problem occurs in this attempt.

```
my_find :: (Num a) => a -> [a] -> Int
my_find n (x : xs) = my_getpos n (my_reverse x : xs)
```

Error messages occur that I am not able to correct. The line **my_find n (x: xs) = my_getpos n (my_reverse x: xs)** makes exactly the occurrence **my_getpos 4 (my_reverse [1,2,3,4,5])**.

In the **my_find** function, I am using the same prototype as the **my_getpos** function, that is, **=> a -> [a] -> Int**.

The message I get is:

```
<interactive>:26:46: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Integer]' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          my_find :: forall a. Num a => a -> [a] -> Int
        at <interactive>:25:1-37
    * In the first argument of `my_reverse', namely `x'
      In the first argument of `(:)', namely `my_reverse x'
      In the second argument of `my_getpos', namely `(my_reverse x : xs)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:26:16)
        x :: a (bound at <interactive>:26:12)
        n :: a (bound at <interactive>:26:9)
        my_find :: a -> [a] -> Int (bound at <interactive>:26:1)
```

Can someone experienced in Haskell help me?

I thank you in advance for the time dedicated to my question.

Comment: Looks like you've just missed some parentheses: `my_reverse x : xs` should be `my_reverse (x : xs)`

Comment: note that you can simplify this as simply `my_find n xs = my_getpos n (reverse xs)`, as you're not using any of the pieces you deconstruct in the pattern match. You could then if you want "factor out" the `xs` argument and write is `my_find n = (my_getpos n) . reverse`

Comment: Hello, Robin Zigmond.

First, I appreciate your availability to assist and the quick return to my question.

You gave me two remarks:

The first I could not understand how. I have already changed parenthesis positions to no avail.

The second uses the "reverse" function and as I said in the post, I need a solution independent of internal language functions. The goal is to write a high enough algorithm with minimal language resources.

Comment: apologies for the use of `reverse`, you can replace that with your `my_reverse` (which does the same thing), I was simply typing too quickly. I'm not sure what you fail to understand about my first comment, which is very explicit. I confess I didn't check your code in detail, it may be there are other problems, but putting these parentheses in is a necessary first step. Please edit your question with the error you get after adding them.

Comment: I already left the message presented in the post. 
In relation to your first observation, I have
"my_find n (x: xs) = my_getpos n (my_reverse x: xs)" for "my_find n (x: xs) = my_getpos n my_reverse (x: xs)" and nothing happened. Error messages continue to appear.

Comment: `my_find n (x: xs) = my_getpos n (my_reverse (x: xs))`. I guarantee that this will make the error you posted go away. That is what you get by altering your code with the exact suggestion I made in my first comment. (I also posted exactly the above, in a simplified form, in my second comment.)

Comment: After reviewing the code I understood exactly what you tried to tell me. Thank you !!!
I had to make a small change to the function prototype. Your guidance is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes after this post, Robin Zigmond spent some time in my attention helping me and giving me the answer. Thank you very much. Share the solution.

```
my_find :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> Int
my_find n (x : xs) = my_getpos n (my_reverse (x: xs))
```

Tchau.

Comment: You might not have noticed that your find function is unnecessarily partial: it does not accept an empty list. (As is already pointed out by Zigmond and not corrected in this answer.) There is really no reason to pattern match on the list. If that partiality was expected, you might not want to make it a non-exhaustive pattern match. (Use `-Wall` and your will see the warning.) Instead, pattern match on the empty list and explicitly error out. By the way, your reverse function runs in squared time, where a linear-time and tail-recursive implementation is possible and well-known.

Comment: Hello, Krantz.

I want to thank you for your time and availability in answering my question and need and giving guidance. I know that the solution I made is not the best, but it meets the objectives of the event in which the subject will be discussed. I inserted in the code the instruction my_find _ [] = error "invalid list". The event is an activity on functional programming logic where the code, reason for doubt, is just an illustration to be made in comparison with other functional languages.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests with Haskell and another functional language just to test the logic. A solution that seemed appropriate, even if it is not the best way, was as follows:

```
my_find :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> Int
my_find _ [] = error "invalid list"
my_find n (x : xs) = my_getpos n (my_reverse (x: xs))
```